# Why does this code not download the file and the downloader can download it successfully

Tags: python, networking

The problem begins with this link
https://i1.pixiv.net/img-zip-ugoira/img/2017/04/05/00/24/41/62259492_ugoira600x600.zip

the file downloaded with the downloader is complete.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vHam.png)

and I try to use python to download the file

```
from urllib import request
import sys
request.urlretrieve('https://i1.pixiv.net/img-zip-ugoira/img/2017/04/05/00/24/41/62259492_ugoira600x600.zip', '123.zip')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ssshooter/PycharmProjects/first/111.py", line 3, in <module>
    request.urlretrieve('https://i1.pixiv.net/img-zip-ugoira/img/2017/04/05/00/24/41/62259492_ugoira600x600.zip', '123.zip')
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ssshooter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: I think we need less pictures and more code perhaps?  As it is I would restate this as "Why does this code not download the file?" as there is only ONE code example here.

Comment: You have the answer in your snippet: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Comment: @kpa6uk  How could the downloader(for example:IDM)  download the complete file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are:

1. You're using different SSL information: You're browser has a built-in set of certificate authorities. Python uses a set which comes with the OS. They differ & if the site you're accessing uses one know to your browser but not known to python, the python will throw an exception.
2. You're accessing using different User-Agents. Your browser is telling the server it's Chrome or IE or whatever. Python is telling the server it's python. For whatever reason, the server may decide it doesn't like that and return Forbidden.
3. The server may be working harder than you think: while it appears the request is for a simple file, you're really requesting a resource. It may be (though unlikely in this case) that the resource you're requesting results in multiple interactions between the server and your browser -- cookies, javascript, etc -- which are executed successfully in your browser, returned to the server & it then delivers the file. Your python request is not doing any of that.
4. Your browser (may) have existing state which your python does not. You say you can access the file using your browser, but it could be that works only because you've accessed other resources on the site, or logged in, or whatever. Your browser is communicating that information (perhaps a session_id via cookie?) with the server recognizes. Your python code states with no previous state, so the server forbids that.

Which is it in this case? You'll need to investigate. Can you get wget or curl to work? Debug your browser's access: what headers are being sent, what are you receiving in reply?

Comment: thanks ! I think the browser had cache a part of the file so that the browser can download an incomplete file,but how could the downloader download the complete file ?

Comment: downloader(for example:IDM)

Comment: @ZhouTK, no, browsers don't cache partial files for download in that way. IDM is really just a multi-protocol program which understands HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc., and has built-in retries, etc. With capabilities somewhere between "browser" and "simple python requests".